# How can I remove 'docked' items in the Cinnamon menu ("start") bar on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

In the menu which appears when you click the `Menu` item on the taskbar in Linux Mint 14 (Cinnamon), you can dock items on the left, by dragging them to the area (there are some default already, like Firefox, or Terminal).

It's easy to rearrange them, or add to them, but **how can I remove ones that I don't want anymore?** I tried dragging it away (and releasing on the desktop, for example), but on release, the icon returns to its place on the dock. There doesn't seem to be a trash icon to drag it into.

If I right-click on the `Menu` option, I can enter `Edit Menu` but while this gives the option to modify the items inside the menu, it doesn't seem to have any options for the dock on the left-hand side.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You just need to drag it over the application menu, though you're right - it seems like any of the ways you mentioned should do it.  (And agreed, none of them do for me either).

[image: NoMoFF]

Comment: Thanks, it's weird I didn't drop it there by chance. I hope they add a visual indicator for this method, or add the other methods mentioned in future releases, but I'm generally happy with Mint now :)

Comment: @ataulm Agreed, it took me a bit to figure it out the first time as well.  Cinnamon is a pretty well done GUI, a great recovery from Gnome3, in my opinion.  Have a great one!

Answer (score 5):

Do the below:
Right click on your Menu start Icon -> "Configure" -> "Open the Menu Editor" -> Scroll to and select the menu item you want to remove -> Delete button on the right hand side.
This should remove the menu item you want to get rid of. You can also edit shortcuts via this way.

Comment: As far as I can tell, this menu does not allow one to remove the 'quick start', left vertical bar icons. I could not find mind in the menus. This only allows one to edit the items in the central area.

Answer (score 3):

Hover mouse over desired left side menu item and press Delete, this will automatically remove the item selected (ex: Firefox, Software Manager, Terminal, Files, Shutdown, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the desired app on the menu. Ex: `All Applications->Internet->Firefox Web Browser`. Right-click on the application. Here you can add/remove from panel, desktop or favorites. The left bar is the favorites.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the gsetting entry "org.cinnamon favorite-apps" , for example with dconf editor. In my case drag and drop was not working.

Comment: Where does one find the dconf editor, how do you use it, and in what way should that be edited?

Comment: You have to install it (search for "dconf editor"). The entry is a list of strings separated by commas. To remove firefox for example, remove the "firefox.desktop" string.

Answer (score 0):

This may be an old posted question but I thought I should chime in anyway since I had the same problem however none of these suggestions worked but I found on the internet a very smart person who knew of a program called Alacarte (easy GNOME menu editing) program it installed using the software manager and I'm thrilled it's still available because it used the be installed by default but isn't now and is not a well known program but I'm so glad it It's still available via software manager and it's so easy to use just click on to highlight the uninstalled program entry you want to get rid of and click delete on the right and it's done. maybe this will help if these other suggestions don't work for you

Answer (score 0):

The file to edit is "/usr/share/cinnamon/applets/menu@cinnamon.org/applet.js".

The entries for "Lock screen" and "Logout" are on line 2479 and 2507 respectively in my system (enable line numbers in preferences).

If you really want to do this, make a copy of the "applet.js" file first so that you can restore it if you make a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

get into :
/USR/SHARE/APPLICATIONS

just revove rights for other users on files you want to hide and keep access for root. it remove the icon for users, but not for admin..

Warning don't touch at cinnamon apps.

enjoy